# Can't run basic laravel homepage

Tags: php, laravel

I have installed xampp (or called lampp) in linux mint 18. Now I have to install laravel. Well the composer installed fine. Since I tried and couldn't get my path right in the .bashrc, I thought of installing by the other method of composer create-project. Now tell me this:-

1. What needs to be added in the .bashrc to run my laravel like magic.
2. If I am installing laravel through composer , do I need to install it in the htdocs folder where by default my lampp is directed to run the php scripts.
3. When testing out laravel do I need to run my lampp servers?

Comment: you have to start apache ,

and run this from laravel root folder 'php artesan serve'  you can see something link 'http://localhost:8000' you can run your laravel project with this link

Comment: could you please tell me where to find the gui of my lampp?

Comment: Where you install larvel

Comment: its in var/www/html

Comment: open your terminal and move to this loaction and run this `php artisan serve`

Comment: I did and got the following error:
PHP Warning:  require(/var/www/html/laravel/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/laravel/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128327/discussion-between-md-hasibur-rahaman-and-goldensquare).

Comment: Do you have vendor folder in your laravel project?

Comment: yes in resources > views